# Declaring a multidimensional array's value to true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can I declare a multidimensional array in Javascript as follows:

```
var linkArray = new Array(3);
linkArray[0][0] = 'boothsize_link';
linkArray[0][1] = true;
linkArray[0][2] = false;
linkArray[1][0] = 'enkfur_link';
linkArray[1][1] = true;
linkArray[1][2] = false;
linkArray[2][0] = 'enklight_link';
linkArray[2][1] = true;
linkArray[2][2] = false;
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not valid, you have to initialize each subarray as well:

```
var linkArray = new Array(3);
linkArray[0] = [];
linkArray[0][0] = 'boothsize_link';
linkArray[0][1] = true;
linkArray[0][2] = false;
etc
```

In general, array initializers are much easier to write using `[...]` literals:

```
var linkArray = [
    ['boothsize_link', true, false],
    ['enkfur_link', true, false],
    etc

]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this valid?

Yes, that's valid JavaScript syntax (apart from the typo `flase`, which will be an undefined variable not a boolean value as expected).

> Will it throw an exception?

Yes. By assigning a new, empty array with a lenght of 3 to `linkArray` does not make the item arrays to whose properties you can assign something. `linkArray[0]` is `undefined`, and `linkArray[0][0]` will throw an error. You would need to call

```
linkArray[0] = new Array(3);
```

before, and the same for `linkArray[1]` and `linkArray[2]` (better be done in a loop).

Or you just use [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals), which are the standard method to declare arrays:

```
var linkArray = [
    ['boothsize_link', true, false],
    ['enkfur_link',    true, flase],
    ['enklight_link',  true, false]
];
```